# how meta refresh has identified at server side to restrict spam sites?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, xss, meta-tags

How to identify whether a page request has been issued by meta refresh, in servlet or java based web application or server side?

I want to restrict a request if that has been issued by meta refresh.

I have tried below js code, but it doesn't solving the issue.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
 for (i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { 
     if (metas[i].getAttribute('http-equiv') == 'refresh') {

    session.setAttribute("source", "meta");

     }
 } 
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't mix Javascript and JSP like that. They run at different times. And you need to explain what you mean by "restrict a request if that has been issued by meta refresh"; count the number of times refreshed and stop it from doing it again, or what?

Comment: And are you wanting to block incoming requests to your site that come via meta-refresh, or are you attempting to create a search engine? What is the goal here?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, i want to block the incoming requests to the site that come via meta-refresh. Since when the site opened in one tab, we can use plain html with meta refresh to open that site in another tab. I understand the same session has been shared among all tabs, that helped meta refresh to open the site without any authentication. In the server side action class unable to identify whether the request is from original tab or from spam request.<html><head>
<meta content="0;url=http://example.com/navigate.do?option=money" http-equiv="refresh" />
</head>
</html>

Comment: You can use meta-refresh to open a different tab? how do you do that?

Comment: When site is open in one tab, we can use meta refresh from plain html, it will send the request to server with same session. since in a browser session is shared among tabs. I want to block those kind of spam request.                                                         <html><head> <meta content="0;url=example.com/navigate.do?option=money"; http-equiv="refresh" /> </head> </html>

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to lock down your application to where users can only have it opened in one tab.  You can't do that. I doubt a user would bother creating an html file with a meta-refresh to open another tab. More likely they'd paste url into another tab, and its perfectly legitimate for them to do so.

Comment: I also have the same thought. But the CSRF(XSS) Attack Prevention requirement says to restrict the meta refresh. If i try to restrict meta refresh using js in my *.jsp file, it's waste of time. Since document.getElementsByTagName('meta') would search 'meta' tag only in particular *.jsp file. But in this case meta tag used in separate  *.* file and send request to server. That's what i'm trying to block spam meta refresh request at server side.

Comment: Well, meta-refresh is always going to come in with the GET method, so if you make your page only respond to POST that will stop it. And POST requests should have a referrer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help in this. I will check and let you know my findings. Thanks lot.

Comment: I'm back. meta-refresh request sent GET method, but can't block all GET requests. Since application already uses GET requests for many page requests, if any form submission is there, then POST used. Is there any other way to identify meta refresh at server side? P.S  If i try to restrict meta refresh using js in my .jsp file, it's waste of time. Since document.getElementsByTagName('meta') would search 'meta' tag only in particular *.jsp file. But in this case meta tag used in separate *. file and send request to server. That's what i'm trying to block meta refresh request at server side.